# Azure Search Instead of Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, azure-cognitive-search

The existing application is running in elasticsearch. The functionality of the application covers.

- MLT search
- synonym search
- stopwords
- multilingual search
- Filtered search

kibana dashboard uses aggregations to show the metrics in the dashboard.

Is it possible to achieve all these functionality in azure-search ?

Answer (score 3):

Azure Search doesn't integrate with Kibana and doesn't support aggregations. All the other functionalities you mentioned are supported in Azure Search. Hope that helps.

Comment: Current azure search documentation states MLT and synonym search are in preview state and not production ready ?

Comment: That's correct. The Synonyms API will be GA very soon, early Q1 2018. We want to do more work on MLT because the scoring is not perfect in some scenarios. Otherwise the feature is stable.

Comment: Azure search does not support aggregations but it does support facets. If I am not mistaken ES renamed facets to aggregations.